# Low stock on category page

Tags: category, stock

I have setup a stock notification "ONLY x LEFT" on a product page.
Could you please advise how to set a "Low Stock" notification on the **category page**?
As below (10 left):

[image: Sample 10 LEFT]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to get the stock qty from your product. The product model does not contain a stock qty so you have to get the right model `(cataloginventory/stock_item)` to get the stock qty.

You can get the qty like this:

```
<?php $qty = intval(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()); ?>
```

The variable $qty contains your products stock qty.
Now you can check if the qty int is lower than x. (in your case 10)

```
<?php if ($qty < 10) { ?>
    Show your awesome image!
<?php } ?>
```